# How can I mimic the calling signature of NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, viewbuilder

I have code like this:

```
    List(datalist) { data in
        NavigationLink(destination: View1(data: data).headless()) {          
            Text(data.name)
        }
    }
```

where headless() is a way to avoid all the default top views of a NavigationLink and its corresponding init:

```
    extension View {
        
        // https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/removing-unwanted-and-unknown-whitespace-possibly-a-navigation-bar-above-a-view/7343
        func headless() -> some View {
            return self.navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is have a View struct that can be a customized call to NavigationLink that always calls the headless() modifier. I have written this, copying from the declaration of NavigationLink:

```
struct SimpleNavLink<Destination, Label>: View where Label : View, Destination : View {
    
    private let label: () -> Label
    private let destination: () -> Destination
    
    init(@ViewBuilder destination: @escaping () -> Destination, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.label = label
        self.destination = destination
    }
    
    var body: some View  {
        NavigationLink(destination: destination().headless, label: label)
    }
    
}
```

With that in place I changed the NavigationLink line to this:

```
SimpleNavLink(destination: View1(data: data)) {
```

But that gave me the error

**Cannot convert value of type 'View1' to expected argument type '() -> Destination'**

That was easy enough to solve by just wrapping the destination in { }:

```
SimpleNavLink(destination: { View1(data: data) } ) {
```

But WHY? I didn't have to do that for the NavigationLink. When I tried adding @autoclosure to the destination parameter, the compiler said that didn't go with @ViewBuilder

Comment: Use `destination: Destination` instead of `destination: () -> Destination` in both places of `SimpleNavLink` and update corresponding usage.

Comment: Here is corrected code https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/Answers/Mimic_NavigationLink.md.

Comment: OK, so what that means is that the destination is generated when the initial page is created, rather than waiting until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> I have written this, copying from the declaration of :

I assume you meant “the declaration of `NavigationLink`”. But your original code uses a `NavigationLink.init` that is declared like this:

```
    @available(iOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Pass a closure as the destination")
    @available(macOS, introduced: 10.15, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Pass a closure as the destination")
    @available(tvOS, introduced: 13.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Pass a closure as the destination")
    @available(watchOS, introduced: 6.0, deprecated: 100000.0, message: "Pass a closure as the destination")
    public init(destination: Destination, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

This version of `init` takes the `Destination` by value instead of as a function. It's also going to be deprecated at some point.

So, if you want to mimic the (eventually deprecated) syntax, you need to change your `init` to take the `Destination` by value instead of as a function. Note also that `NavigationLink` does **not** require `@escaping` closures, so perhaps you shouldn't either. Thus:

```
struct SimpleNavLink<Destination: View, Label: View>: View {
    private let label: Label
    private let destination: Destination

    init(
        destination: Destination,
        @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label
    ) {
        self.label = label()
        self.destination = destination
    }

    var body: some View  {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: destination.headless(),
            label: { label }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proofreading. Yes, I had left something out